# Insufficient Space on Mobile Device

Tags: insufficient-memory, storage

I have searched for an answer to my question because many others have asked this before me - but i guess i have to find more creative answers because all the given answers don't really work for me.

I am trying to install a new app of 18.1 MB but it's impossible. What can I do?

- I un-installed 2 apps (together should be more than 18.1 MB)
- I only have a few downloaded apps (mostly linked to google like google play music, google play newsstand etc) but still its says with Application Manager > Downloaded > 1.7 GB used ( Id say thats too much), 315 MB free
  (and with those apps I uninstalled all updates)
- I have an SD card , which has space, but I cannot move any of my apps there

Maybe its time for a new phone

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I highly recommend to check with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for a starter. Gives you some background and first-aid. Then come back here and either [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) (when solved), or [edit] it to include what you've tried and where you're stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur when your memory cache is insufficient.

When you download an app, the data goes in the cache so that the phone can install it when the download is completed.

---

In order to be sure that this is the problem, try to download smaller apps. There must be a point where the size is small enough for your android to install it.

I had this problem on my Acer Stream years ago and this is what the support told me, which was right. What is your smartphone model ?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the case. Follow the comments here and the links posted in them. ["Insufficient storage" when trying to install new app](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/149760)

Comment: @Firelord Your link is off topic : It's not the same error, the answer you link to clearly says that we are not in this case (neither with the 10% nor the 25Mb). Please let Floor, the one who asked the question, determine if answers we provide help or not.

Comment: I said follow the comments, not the answer and the links in the comments. It's not like system would tell you by any notification or toast that it is following a 10% rule.

Answer (score -1):

you can try out the following methods to get most of your internal storage back:

Look for LOST.dir folder in your internal SD
If you frequently transfer lots of files between your Android device and PC or MAC, chances are there are huge recovered corrupted files in your LOST.dir folder. In my case I had about 2GB of those. Is it safe to delete them? Yes. Deleting the Lost.dir folder will not cause any harm. However, if important files such as Clockword Recovery files are corrupted, chances are that they have ended in Lost.dir, you might want to try and recover them using Recuva or other similar software. Follow this thread if you have want to recover your lost clockworkmod recovery files.
No matter how many times you delete this folder, chances are it will be recreated each time you transfer files and mount/unmount your device. You can prevent those large files from piling up in LOST.DIR by always safely ejecting or unmounting your android from the PC or MAC and by avoiding  dismounting or ejection at the middle of a transfer

Look for large thumbnail files in DCIM folder in the internal storage
A common issue experienced by many android users is that their pictures and videos folder (DCIM) increases in size by itself i.e. even when no picture or video is taken. It appears that overtime large thumbnail files are created by your default gallery and have sizes that are far greater than the actual images. This is some sort of bug which still awaits a solution. However as a temporary fix you can simply delete the large files in the
mnt/SDcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
folder. I freed a total of 1.5 GB by deleting those files.
You might also want to install Quickpic and use it instead of default gallery to browse and view pictures. Quickpic gallery loads up very fast, has a clean interface and is currently the best gallery replacement for your Android. Download Quickpic

Install Cleanmaster to delete junk files
Cleanmaster is a really nice app which will clean your system cache, residual files from apps previously uninstalled or deleted and also delete your unwanted search histories, call logs etc. I saved over 600mb via this app. However, you might want to de-select some cache files that are important. For example- I use Pulse reader and once your news are loaded in the app, you can view them without network connection later. Hence, before cleaning, I uncheck Pulse from the list of caches.
Run Cleanmaster at least once a week to avoid system cache from piling up later. Download Cleanmaster

Link2SD 
Link2SD is a simple application which will allow your rooted Android to force move apps to external storage or SDcard, This will save you lots of internal storage. With Link2SD even system apps are converted into user apps so that you can move them out of phone memory.This means you can now install apps beyond the limited internal system memory. Download Link2SD.
Note: It is better to partition your SD card for storing apps on your SD via Link2SD.  It is very easy to partition if you have Clockworkmod recovery installed. Most rooted devices have this. First turn off or restart your phone into recover mode. From there, select advanced->partition SD Card. From there, select how much space you want to allocate for that partition. Alternatively, you can install and use partition tools on your PC.There is one called . From the minitool wizard you can select your SDcard, format it and then partition it into primary and extra partition using the “Create” button. From there, select Fat32 as your SDcard’s file system and allocate space for your primary partition and secondary partition. Now when you open Link2SD you can select your new partition. Then, select the apps from the internal storage that you want to move to your SD. Then click on the action button to and click create link.Now, check all the three boxes and click “OK” to create links.  Now all your internal storage apps are moved to SD card. To make your external SD as default storage for apps and games, go to settings -> Auto Link -> Now, Check all three boxes and press ok.
As you can see, I managed to free more than 4GB of space by following these methods to clean unwanted files eating up my android’s internal storage. Go ahead and try these solutions and free up loads of space in your Android device.

Comment: And what if there isn't a 1GB thumbnail in the thumbnail folder under DCIM? Please elaborate the answer.

Comment: then only cache needs to be cleared  with cache cleaner .